# @RegExpr Regular Expression doesn't work

Tags: regex, vb6

I have a table which contains a column named TEST and I must get the lines of this column that contains a certain word, for example "pro".

I use **@RegExpr** for doing this but I don't know why it doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
@RegExpr(@Lower( TEST),@lower("\\bpro\\b"))
```

Comment: is your code vba or vb6?

Comment: it is in vb6 language

Comment: How are you interfacing with your table? You could just use the SQL `Like` operator to return rows that contain certain text. For example, `select * from table where col like '%pro%'`.